# OpenMDAO v2: How to perform dynamic optimization?

Tags: optimization, dynamic, controls, openmdao

I am trying to solve a dynamic optimization problem (optimal control), that is a problem in which the control variables and objective change with respect to time. [Optimal Control Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlVnI.png) is an example of mathematical formulation of the problem.
I am quite new to using OpenMDAO but it seems so powerful that I think I might find a way to model the system to control and solve the optimal control problem (OCP) with it. My issue is that I don't know how to handle dynamics in OpenMADO. The examples I have seen use static design variables and objectives. However, an OCP has been solved by Robert D. Falck *et al*. in [Trajectory Optimization of Electric Aircraft](http://openmdao.org/pubs/falck_traj_opt_electric_2017.pdf). Additional work was also done by Hendicks *et al.*[integrating propulsion models with trajectory optimization](http://openmdao.org/pubs/hendricks_pointer_pycycle_2017.pdf) and by Hwang on [variable time discritizations](http://openmdao.org/pubs/hwang_reconfigurability_2017.pdf).

It would have been so great if I could have a view on how they did it with OpenMDAO.
Can someone explain me ho I can do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is not a programming question please find a suitable platform to ask the question https://stackexchange.com/sites# so you can be answered by relevant people.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2017, the OpenMDAO team isn't ready to release any of the optimal control or ODE libraries that are being developed on top of OpenMDAO. Its an active area or research for the team and we're still developing the underlying libraries. They aren't yet ready for public consumption.

We hope to have some initial capability publicly releasable by June 2018 time frame.

Comment: Thanks for your edit and your kind reply. I am looking forward to seeing a new OpenMDAO release supporting OCP.

Comment: Justin, we're working on adding Python Gekko as a dynamic optimization module to another design optimization framework in Python. Because MDAO does a good job at integrating other tools for sub-optimization calls, could Gekko be an option to add optimal control / ODE / DAE solutions? https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/